Handling InterruptedException inside a loop - Loop should finish
I am writing a program that copies files from A to B. Due to outside constraints, we cannot copy all files at once or can use any Java file copying mechanism (constraints like copy with different dates, use files rights of goal directory, etc.).
Instead, we have to use robocopy as a command line tool for each file individually and then write a report for each file if copying was a success or a failure. If the robocopy call takes too long, we kill the process that runs it, which throws a InterruptedException that needs to be handled.
We use a ProcessBuilder to create a Process object.
Here, the waitFor(timoutTime, timeUnit) call throws the InterruptedException(), since it interrupts the process once time ran out.
// Wait for the process to complete
if (!process.waitFor(timeoutTime, timeUnit)) {
    // If time has passed, kill it.
    process.destroy();
    // If it is not killed in 1 minute again with more force.
    process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    process.destroyForcibly();
}

Even though we call a new process for copying, we want to have a single-threaded like performance, where each File is copied one after another. This is by choice and should remain that way.
Since we want the loop to finish, the first idea was to catch the exception, write an error report and deal with the next file. However, this is bad practice and Sonar recommends either rethrowing the exception or interrupting the current Thread.
Problem is:

We do not want to interrupt the current thread, only the process, which is already killed. The current Thread should keep on running until all files are worked through, so it can return a report like this:


File A success
File B failure
File C success
...


Re-throwing the failure will also abort the loop. A idea I had was to consume the exception, set a flag and after all is done, re-throw it, but this also does not comply with best practice.

So here is the question:
How do I handle InterruptedException in an application that needs to perform multiple action that can throw the exception after one another, but need to perform each action?

What is the specific complaint sonar makes?

Does this answer your question? Handling InterruptedException in Java

So i guess if you want to make sonarqube happy you can set the interrupt flag on the current thread, (Thread.currentThread().interrupt()), but make sure you clear the flag with Thread.interrupted() before you process the next file.

I'd suggest adding an @SuppressWarning("java:<sonaridentifier>") (with <sonaridentifier> the actual warning) to the method. Sonar is nice to make you think, but it is not always right, or it might be too much effort to satisfy Sonar without actually providing an actual benefit. You are the developer: you are in the driving seat, not Sonar.

Though keep in mind than in general you should stop what you're doing if you receive an InterruptedException, because generally it signals that your thread or application should stop doing what it's doing, and not doing so might mean your application needs to be killed hard instead of being able to exit gracefully when needed (e.g. computer shutdown, server reboot, etc).


So here is the question: How do I handle InterruptedException in an application that needs to perform multiple action that can throw the exception after one another, but need to perform each action?

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question but you handle the InterruptedException exactly like any other exception -- you catch it and swallow it.

Here, the waitFor(timoutTime, timeUnit) call throws the InterruptedException, since it interrupts the process once time ran out.

Be careful here.  If waitFor(...) throws InterruptedException the thread that is calling the method has been interrupted.  It is not that the Process that is being waited-for has been interrupted.  See the javadocs for waitFor(...).

this is bad practice and Sonar recommends either rethrowing the exception or interrupting the current Thread

I would agree that it is bad practice but like with other exceptions, sometimes we need to mask them so we can complete some task.  One thing to consider would be to catch the InterruptedException and save it so you can re-throw it at the end after all of your files are processed.  Also, when you catch InterruptedException, the interrupt bit on the current thread is going to be cleared.  If you catch and swallow the exception then at the end you should re-interrupt the thread with Thread.currentThread().interrupt();.  Always a good practice.
Also, because this is a somewhat unique situation, I would make sure that your loop is well commented to explain for maintainers (most likely future you) what you are doing.
